# I'm getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in my bundle.js

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, boilerplate, babel-polyfill

I am trying to set up a boilerplate for react web apps.

However,  every time I navigate to http://localhost:8080/, I get an error saying: Uncaught SyntaxError: `Unexpected token <` . In my bundle.js.

I have no idea what to do! Thanks for any help.

Here are some of my files:

**/public/index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>New app</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
   <script src="./bundle.js" defer> .</script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**/client/app.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>Hello, world!</div>,
  document.getElementById('app') 
);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: [
'@babel/polyfill', // enables async-await
'./client/app.js',
  ],
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: `./public/bundle.js`,
  },
  devtool: 'source-maps',
  module: {
     rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "boilerplatelivmarx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server",
    "start-dev": "webpack -w & nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Unexpected token <` <= is an error generally encountered when the web server returns `html` instead of `json` or `javascript`. That could happen because the web server returns an error page, maybe due to insufficient rights or a wrong/malformed URL being called. Use the browsers network tab to see what the actual result value is that was retrieved.

Comment: What is in your bundle file? Is it loading or it is returning a 404 or something? It could also be that the babel-loader isn't correctly changing your JSX.

Comment: Why do all your files have backticks at the beginning and end? If those were intended as code markdown, they're not needed when you indent the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is wrong [`jsx` processing](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react);

Add react preset to your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
...
use: {
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    presets: ['react']
  }
},
...
```

Also, looks like you try to use [`@babel/polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill), but did not install it.

Run:

```bash
npm i @babel/polyfill
```

And you don't need dot in `<script>` at your `index.html` file:

```html
<!--                             ↓      -->
<script src="./bundle.js" defer> .</script>
```

After that, everything must build:

[image]

And run:

[image]